# How to select from table A and then insert selected id inside table B with one query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to implement a very basic banking system.
the goal is to have different types of transactions ( deposit, withdraw, transfer ) inside a table and refer to them as IDs inside transaction tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE transaction_types (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  type_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  amount FLOAT NOT NULL
)
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. When inserting into `transactions` table no record can have an invalid `type_id` ( `type_id` should exist in `transaction_types` table )
2. First of all get `type_id` from `transaction_types` table and then insert inside `transactions` table, with one query ( if it's possible, I'm fairly new )

I'm using Node.js/Typescript and PostgreSQL, any help is appreciated a lot.

Comment: You accomplish the first with a foreign key constraint.  I don't understand (2).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, about the second one, Let's say a user wants to withdraw the money, and I want to insert this record inside transactions table, first I want to know what id does `withdraw` have in transaction_types and then insert accordingly to transactions table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1): modify Transactions table definition by adding `REFERENCES transaction_types(id)` to the end of the type_id column definition prior to the comma.

For (2), assuming you know the name of the transaction_type, you can accomplish this by:

```
INSERT INTO transactions(type_id, amount) 
VALUES ((SELECT id from transaction_types WHERE name = 'Withdrawal'), 999.99)
```

By the way, my PostgreSQL requires `SERIAL` instead of `INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT`